# Simple HttpWebRequest POST with Redirect URL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, httpwebrequest

Here I have simple HTML page that make a POST to other page.
After I fill out that form and press  `Submit`  it takes me back to  `callback`  URL.

```
<form action="http://somedomain/products/cotd" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="callback" value="http://DOMAIN.org">
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

Now I need to implement the same in ASP.NET

```
Private Sub post()
    Dim req2 As HttpWebRequest
    Dim resp As HttpWebResponse
    dim result As string
    dim url = "http://somedomain/products/cotd"
    url += "?callback=http://DOMAIN.org"

    Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
    req.Method = "POST"

    req2 = CType(req, HttpWebRequest)
    req2.AllowAutoRedirect = true

    resp = TryCast(req2.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    result = getResponse(resp)
    resp.Close()
End Sub

function getResponse(response as HttpWebResponse) As string
    Dim responseText As String

    Dim encoding1 = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII
    Using reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding1)
        responseText = reader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using

    Return responseText
End function
```

The thing is nothing happens here. Neither the new page opens neither it redirects back. IN a response I do get callback page but first it does not open page where I need to submit values.

What am I missing here please?

Comment: Through, `HttpWebResponse` you can get response. You cannot actually redirect to that page.

Comment: you are missing out the content length and content-type for the req, the req built has not been posted with streamwriter.